# PayPal Create Payment: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I have tried to find similar issue but apparently there's none so hopefully I did not create duplicate thread.

Anyway, I have tried PayPal SDK and fill up OAuthTokenCredential with proper Client ID and Client Secret that I get from my developer account in developer.paypal.com.

However, when I try to call Payment object which is payment.Create(Api), I received PayPalException:

> Invalid HTTP response The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>
> [ConnectionException: Invalid HTTP response The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
>      PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest httpRequest) +1275
>
> [PayPalException: Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Invalid HTTP response The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
>      PayPal.PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute(APIContext apiContext, HttpMethod httpMethod, String resource, Dictionary`2 headersMap, String payLoad) +1981
>      PayPal.PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute(APIContext apiContext, HttpMethod httpMethod, String resource, String payLoad) +93
>      PayPal.Api.Payments.Payment.Create(APIContext apiContext) +186

I am not too sure, but should we handle it in the Developer account itself or something is missing in my code?

Thank you!

```
        FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
        CreditCardToken creditCardToken = new CreditCardToken();
        creditCardToken.credit_card_id = GetSignedInUserCreditCardID(email);
        fundingInstrument.credit_card_token = creditCardToken;

        List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstrumentList = new List<FundingInstrument>();
        fundingInstrumentList.Add(fundingInstrument);

        Payer payer = new Payer();
        payer.funding_instruments = fundingInstrumentList;
        payer.payment_method = paymntMethod.ToString();


        Payment pyment = new Payment();
        pyment.intent = "sale";
        pyment.payer = payer;
        pyment.transactions = transactions;         
        try
        {
            pay = pyment.Create(Api);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
```

Comment: You need to share your code and tag the question as part of that language

Comment: thanks! this is the code in c#. The error returns when I try to create the payment in this line "pay = pyment.Create(Api)"

Comment: Is this on sandbox or with the live service?  I noticed you're making a payment using a vaulted card.  Are you able to get the details of the card using the `CreditCard.Get()` call?

Comment: It's on sandbox. Sorry but what is vaulted card? Did you refer to CreditCardToken class for Get method?

Comment: A [vaulted credit card](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/) is a credit card that is stored by PayPal and can be re-used via a credit card token.  To check that you have a valid token, you can call [`CreditCard.Get()`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Source/SDK/Api/CreditCard.cs#L148) with the `credit_card_id` to retrieve the details.  If that comes back with correct information, then we can rule that out.  Also, does the 404 response include any details in the response body?